# Does it make a difference to use a VPN to access home services?

Tags: vpn

Situation: I want to set up some home servers that can store my files. Currently in the planning stage of the setup.

Problem: Security and stuff comes to mind when doing such things, especially exposed servers.

Question: Does it make a difference if I set up a VPN server at home and only expose the VPN server vs exposing the file server (or any other server for that matter) to the internet?

Comment: Why do you suggest that you have to expose your file server **and** any other server to the internet? If you configure it correctly, you can only expose the file server to the internet.

Comment: Say for example I have a web server running together. Sorry if the question is a little unclear

Comment: If you have a file server running on port 8080, then you can run a web server on port 443 and just choose to expose port 8080.

Comment: I can do that -- but the question is whether tunneling through a home VPN server makes any difference vs accessing the web server directly from the internet. But it's okay -- accepted answer has addressed this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *don't* use a VPN, then ask yourself the following questions:

- How would the connection from your client to your file server be encrypted?
- How would the client and the server mutually authenticate each other?
- How would the keys used to build this encrypted connection be managed on the client and the server?
- How strong is the encryption, and how strong are the keys?

VPN's are used, because they provide reasonably good solutions to all of the above problems.

If your public-facing file server provides acceptable solutions to all of the problems above, then *maybe* you can consider accessing the server directly, without using a VPN.  For example, using key-based authentication with an SSH server may be an acceptable solution in your case.

But even in this case, if the VPN is integrated with a hardware firewall protecting the server, this provides an additional layer of security - because the hardware firewall blocks stray packets from random bots, etc. from even reaching your server.  This way, in the event that a vulnerability is discovered in the file server (which would otherwise be public-facing without the VPN/firewall), the server is still protected by the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes a difference. It makes the setup much more secure, especially if you use 2FA for your VPN accesss. So go ahead and do it!